# Basic4Android - Fill ListView and ScrollView after screen rotation

Tags: basic4android

how can I save the ListView and  ScrollView items that contain text and images, in order to restore them after screen rotation? The data are imported on run-time.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your `ListView` and `ScrollView` variables in the `Sub Globals` event. Load them in the `Sub Activity_Create` event when you load your layout, and they should just work.

If this isn't what you wanted, edit your question and provide more details (including the event code that's loading your data) to provide more info.